# How best to use the phrase “on the whole”?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, phrase-requests

Is the phrase *on the whole* used correctly in the following sentence?

> The information, on the whole, was inaccurate.

If not, what other ways are there to express it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically a correct usage: *on the whole* means *generally speaking, all things considered*. The one quibble I have is that facts cannot be inaccurate. Facts are, by definition, accurate.

You could say:

> The information, on the whole, was inaccurate.

Or:

> The data, on the whole, was inaccurate.

For what it is worth, using it parenthetically here is a little clumsy in my view, though certainly not wrong, and certainly understandable. I’d rather you put it at the start:

> On the whole, the data was inaccurate.

Comment: The reported facts, on the whole, ..

Comment: edited post to say "the information"